# "Incidence diagrams" and equivariant connections in a paper on Hodge theory

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, hodge-theory

I am trying to read M. Kapranov's paper "[Real mixed Hodge structures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.0215.pdf)". He defines (over $\mathbb C$) a category $\operatorname{Bun}_\nabla(\mathbb A^2; \mathbb G_m^2) $of vector bundles on $\mathbb A^2$, invariant under the natural action of $\mathbb G_m^2$ and equipped with an invariant connection.

He then defines the dual projective plane $\mathbb {P^2}^\vee$ of lines in $\mathbb P^2$, and sets $\mathbb {P^2}^\vee_0 = \mathbb {P^2}^\vee \setminus \{[1:0:0]\}$.

Then, on page 5, he gives "incidence diagrams". Please refer to (1.2.2) in the paper I linked.

My question is simple: What are $Q_0$ and $Q$ in this diagram? He doesn't define these objects anywhere in the paper.

Comment: I've posted an answer below, but can I ask more generally what your background is? Incidence correspondences are a pretty basic construction in algebraic geometry; are you coming from a differential geometry background or something like that? If so, it might help to have a copy of Harris' *Algebraic Geometry, a First Course* or Shafarevich's *Basic AG* on hand.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your answer and for the references! My background is in number theory. I've read Hartshorne and I know some etale cohomology, but hadn't come across any incidence diagrams.

Comment: To paraphrase my advisor, Hartshorne's book is not interested in teaching you algebraic geometry; it's trying to teach you *EGA*. The amount of very basic geometry that is not covered in that book is mind-blowing at times; IIRC Grassmannians don't even get a mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Q_0$ is the set of pairs $(x,L) \in \mathbb{A}^2 \times \mathbb{P}_0^{2\vee}$ such that $x \in L$, while $Q$ is the extension to the full $\mathbb P^2$ and its dual.